# How to inject an object into sqlalchemy session?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to use tracking system of sqlalchemy as an ORM. I want to inject a ready model object (which is inherited from Base and can be used in sqlalchemy) into a ready session obejct without connecting to database. I tried doing session.merge(obj, load=False) with no success! It complains about the object state. I can't imagine how I can seduce it. I just want to inject the object and then make changes and use session.dirty to track the changes. When using merge with load=True (default) anything works. But I strongly refuse to connect to database via the session for a reason.

```
class Alaki(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'alaki'

    alaki_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(LocalizedString)
    age = Column(Integer)
    children = relationship('AlakiChildren')

model = Alaki(alaki_id=5, name='test',age=32)
self.db_session.merge(model)  # Works but connects to database
self.db_session.merge(model, load=False) #Fails!

for item in self.db_session.dirty:
    print('dirty:' ,item)
```

Comment: Please give a solution to use SqlAlchemy tracking without reading data from database.